# jquery fadeandscale popup closing not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, popup

I'm using fadeandscale popup plugin from http://vast-engineering.github.io/jquery-popup-overlay/
And it is working all good but only problem is it is not closing/canceling while clicking on cancel button. I've tried with the guide lines and manually too but it doesn't respond anything. 
here is my online sample for better understanding..

http://goo.gl/ckAvgV

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem got solved by putting close/cancel outside of iframe. Thanks for your time :)